# Template partial specialization for integral non-type parameters and non-integral non-types, difference between g++ and clang

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

### The following is a simple template partial specialization:

```
// #1
template <typename T, T n1, T n2>
struct foo { 
    static const char* scenario() {
        return "#1 the base template";
    }
};

// #2
// partial specialization where T is unknown and n1 == n2
template <typename T, T a>
struct foo<T, a, a> { 
    static const char* scenario() {
        return "#2 partial specialization";
    }
};
```

The main below gets different results on `g++ (6.1)` and `clang++ (3.8.0)`:

```
extern const char HELLO[] = "hello";
double d = 2.3;

int main() {
    cout <<   foo<int, 1, 2>                    ::scenario() << endl;                   
    cout <<   foo<int, 2, 2>                    ::scenario() << endl;                   
    cout <<   foo<long, 3, 3>                   ::scenario() << endl;                  
    cout <<   foo<double&, d, d>                ::scenario() << endl;               
    cout <<   foo<double*, &d, &d>              ::scenario() << endl;             
    cout <<   foo<double*, nullptr, nullptr>    ::scenario() << endl;   
    cout <<   foo<int*, nullptr, nullptr>       ::scenario() << endl;      
    cout <<   foo<nullptr_t, nullptr, nullptr>  ::scenario() << endl; 
    cout <<   foo<const char*, HELLO, HELLO>    ::scenario() << endl;
}
```

### Results on `g++` and `clang++`

`# | The code                          | g++ (6.1)       |  clang++ (3.8.0) |`
`1 | foo<int, 1, 2>                    | #1 as expected  |  #1 as expected  |`
`2 | foo<int, 2, 2>                    | #2 as expected  |  #2 as expected  |`
`3 | foo<long, 3, 3>                   | #2 as expected  |  #2 as expected  |`
`4 | foo<double&, d, d>                | #1 -- why?      |  #2 as expected  |`
`5 | foo<double*, &d, &d>              | #2 as expected  |  #2 as expected  |`
`6 | foo<double*, nullptr, nullptr>    | #2 as expected  |  #1 -- why?      |`
`7 | foo<int*, nullptr, nullptr>       | #2 as expected  |  #1 -- why?      |`
`8 | foo<nullptr_t, nullptr, nullptr>  | #2 as expected  |  #1 -- why?      |`
`9 | foo<const char*, HELLO, HELLO>    | #2 as expected  |  #2 as expected  |`

### Which one is right?

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/4GfYqxKn3

---

<sub>**EDIT, Dec-2021:**</sub>

<sub>Along the years since the original post, the results have changed, [and were even identical for `gcc` and `clang` at a certain point in time](https://godbolt.org/z/sadnWrsb9), but checking again, `g++ (11.2)` and `clang++ (12.0.1)` [changed their results on references (case 4), but still differ on it](https://godbolt.org/z/97ajTMc3e). It seems that currently `gcc` is getting it all right and `clang` is wrong on the reference case.</sub>

`# | The code                          | g++ (11.2)      | clang++ (12.0.1) |`
`1 | foo<int, 1, 2>                    | #1 as expected  |  #1 as expected  |`
`2 | foo<int, 2, 2>                    | #2 as expected  |  #2 as expected  |`
`3 | foo<long, 3, 3>                   | #2 as expected  |  #2 as expected  |`
`4 | foo<double&, d, d>                | #2 as expected  |  #1 -- why?      |`
`5 | foo<double*, &d, &d>              | #2 as expected  |  #2 as expected  |`
`6 | foo<double*, nullptr, nullptr>    | #2 as expected  |  #2 as expected  |`
`7 | foo<int*, nullptr, nullptr>       | #2 as expected  |  #2 as expected  |`
`8 | foo<nullptr_t, nullptr, nullptr>  | #2 as expected  |  #2 as expected  |`
`9 | foo<const char*, HELLO, HELLO>    | #2 as expected  |  #2 as expected  |`

Comment: I'm with you. Both compilers fails in their respective cases. clang is right for #4, gcc is right for #6, #7, and #8.

Comment: There are many quirks related to function specialization; see [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Comment: @EissaN, note that this is a specialization for a struct, not a function. Though I agree this is indeed in the quirk zone...

Comment: MSVC produces all the expected results as a matter of fact.

Comment: EDG in C++14 strict mode also selects the partial specialization as expected.

Comment: Interestingly, g++ 4.8 gives #2 for the 4th case

Comment: For 6 and 7, their is an implicit conversion. I'm not quite sure of what equality check the compiler perfoms. Maybe the two conversions to double* (and int*) gives two different objects, compared by reference by clang...

Comment: I'd like to add that gcc 7.2 and clang 4.0.0 are the earliest versions respectively to give all expected results: https://godbolt.org/z/g6imAK

Comment: Fast forwarding to 2020, `g++ 7.5.0` and `clang 8.0.0` give identical (correct) results

Comment: it might be the implementation of nullptr in case with nullptrs. Note, that way how template specialization is defined, it should be identical objects, not equal objects. so two non-trivial temporaries (and early nullptr was  such) would be  not be same.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom funny enough clang and gcc now switched places in relation to #4 (as of gcc 12  it's #2, and clang 13  chooses #1). They agree on #6-#8

Comment: Hy, I tested something else, the flags -std=c++20 -Werror -pedantic -Wall -Wextra, then everything works as expected even with the following line `TEST(foo<double, 2.0, 2.0>);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will dedicate my answer to case #4, because according to the OP's EDIT, the compilers now agree on cases #6-8:

> `# | The code                          | g++ (6.1)       |  clang++ (3.8.0) |`
>
> `4 | foo<double&, d, d>                | #1 -- why?      |  #2 as expected  |`

Seems like `clang++ 3.8.0` behaves correctly and `gcc 6.1` rejects the perfectly fine partial specialization for this case because of the following bug that was fixed in `gcc 7.2`:

[Bug 77435 - Dependent reference non-type template parameter not matched for partial specialization](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77435)

There is a [diff](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git&a=commit;h=3da557ec145823c3f51ff3fa7c619d0064134800) there with this key change in the compiler's code:

```
// Was: else if (same_type_p (TREE_TYPE (arg), tparm))
else if (same_type_p (non_reference (TREE_TYPE (arg)), non_reference(tparm)))
```

Before `gcc 7.2`, when a dependent type `T&` was matched with argument of type `T` in a parital specialization candidate, the compiler falsely rejected it. This behavior can be demostrated in a cleaner example:

```
template <typename T, T... x>
struct foo { 
    static void scenario() { cout << "#1" << endl; }
};

// Partial specialization when sizeof...(x) == 1
template <typename T, T a>
struct foo<T, a> { 
    static void scenario() { cout << "#2" << endl; }
};
```

In the case of `T = const int` the behavior of `gcc 6.1` and `gcc 7.2` is the same:

```
const int i1 = 1, i2 = 2;
foo<const int, i1, i2>::scenario(); // Both print #1
foo<const int, i1>::scenario();     // Both print #2
```

But in case of `T = const int&` the behavior of `gcc 6.1` is to reject the correct partial specialization and choose the base implementation instead:

```
foo<const int&, i1, i2>::scenario(); // Both print #1
foo<const int&, i1>::scenario();     // gcc 6.1 prints #1 but gcc 7.2 prints #2
```

It affects any reference type, here are some more examples:

```
double d1 = 2.3, d2 = 4.6;

struct bar {};
bar b1, b2;

foo<double&, d1, d2>::scenario(); // Both print #1
foo<double&, d1>::scenario();     // gcc 6.1 prints #1 but gcc 7.2 prints #2
foo<bar&, b1, b2>::scenario();    // Both print #1
foo<bar&, b1>::scenario();        // gcc 6.1 prints #1 but gcc 7.2 prints #2
```

You can run this example here: https://godbolt.org/z/Y1KjazrMP

`gcc` seems to make this mistake up to `gcc 7.1` but from `gcc 7.2` up to the current version it chooses the partial specialization correctly because of the bugfix above.

In conclusion, case #4's result in the question is just a symptom of a more general problem and it happens just because `double&` is a reference type. To demonstrate this claim, try to add the following line in the OP's code (and `bar`, `b1` definitions from my example):

```
cout << foo<bar&, b1, b1>::scenario() << endl;
```

and observe that `gcc 6.1` prints again `"#1 the base template"` while `gcc 7.2` and onward prints `"#2 partial specialization"` as expected.

---

### EDIT

Regarding the follow-up question in the OP's EDIT:

> `# | The code                          | g++ (11.2)      | clang++ (12.0.1) |`
>
> `4 | foo<double&, d, d>                | #2 as expected  |  #1 -- why?      |`

I think that `g++ (11.2)` is correct.

Pay attention that `clang` wasn't flipped its answer entirely because in your link, you have used `c++20` standard but if you change it back to `c++14` as in the original question, even `clang++ 12.0.1` agrees with `g++ 11.2` and chooses the parial specialization.

Actually, it happens with `clang` in `c++17` too and it seems to be an issue in `clang` that started with this standard and isn't fixed until today.

If you try to add the following test case to your code:

```
TEST (foo<const int, 2, 2>); // clang (c++17/20) prints #1 and gcc (any) prints #2
```

`clang` also chooses the base template instead of the partial specialization like `gcc` while in this test case:

```
TEST (foo<int, 2, 2>); // Both agree on #2
```

they both agree, which I find odd, because this added `const` to the type shouldn't impact the partial specialization's fitness and it seems like `clang` doesn't do that for references only, but for consts as well! and only when the standard >= C++17.

BTW, this issue can be reproduced in my example too:
https://godbolt.org/z/W9q83j3Pq

Observe that `clang 8.0.0` disagrees with itself just by changing the language standard and it keeps doing that up to `clang 13.0.0` even on such a simple case when no argument value equality required.

These odd template deductions in `clang` raise enough "red flags" so I must conclude that `g++ (11.2)` is correct.

My wild guess is - C++17 introduced [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), which make `clang` act differently with class template deduction, and this issue is somehow connected to its new implementation while the old C++14 implementation stayed intact.

Comment: Interesting! Well done Tal, this is a very thorough investigation for the gcc history, pointing at the actual fix that made the change. It would be interesting even more to understand why clang reverted to what seems like a bad behavior, after it was already conforming with the expected result for references.

Comment: I don't think the second part explores clang's behavior sufficiently. It seems very likely to me that the different behavior of clang for different language flags is a result of [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/diff.cpp14.temp#1) breaking change in C++17 which introduced deduction of types from non-type template arguments. Such deduction is done to test whether the partial specialization matches and then the non-trivial question is whether https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.type#13 implies a deduction conflict for `T` (which Clang seems to assume).

Comment: In fact GCC (and MSVC) seem to not really know how the deduction is supposed to happen under these conditions, since they both manage to pass `static_assert`s that seem to indicate different types for the same template parameter: https://godbolt.org/z/GEsa6KaWP This makes me think that Clang may actually be correct.

Comment: The breaking change seems to involve a deduction of `T` but in this question, `T` is not deduced but given explicitly by the user as `T = double&` inside the template parameter-list, without a deduction from a function argument like in your example. In the case that `T` is explicitly chosen directly, I think there shouldn't be any type conflicts. Also, I added your `static_assert` to the original question's code and it seems like both intercepted all the relevant types as `double&` and not `double` https://godbolt.org/z/4Kd5q3Ev1 and also in the answer's example https://godbolt.org/z/KEqKdonzn

Comment: @TalSarid See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71087779/type-conflicts-in-non-type-template-argument-deduction). As indicated by the links in its comment, there doesn't seem to be anything in the standard saying that deduction of `T` from `a`'s argument doesn't happen. The same type deduction in that question should be used to determine whether the partial specialization here matches. Regarding the `static_assert` I just wanted to show that there seems to be some related issue with GCC, so it's behavior maybe shouldn't be that trusted. The same goes for MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with determining what is correct according to the C++ standard, and compare that to the actual compilers. I am pretty sure, that it should work the same, as you expect, i.e. `#1` for the first case and `#2` for all the rest (although some caveats apply, see later).

As `evzh` pointed out in his comment (Jul 1 2020 at 3:30), gcc 7.2 and clang 4.0.0 are the earliest versions that work correctly. They work correctly all the way up to the latest versions with `-std=c++11`.

And here is caveat. Clang works differently when you increase `-std` from `c++14` to `c++17`. In the question in **EDIT, Dec-2021** you are using `-std=c++20`, which is after `c++17`. That is why you experienced the `why?` case.

My assumption is that the compilers had bugs in 2016 where they differed from the above established correct behavior, and clang 12.0.1 with `-std=c++17` or greater still has a bug in case of `foo<double&, d, d>`.

Clang is a very pedantic compiler, so I might be wrong. There is a little chance, that something changed in the standard, that makes clang correct and the other compilers wrong. This is worth being asked in a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71022302/11279879).

Here is a simplified test to demonstrate all your cases: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7GWrdTqGe). I have added four compilers to show how `foo<double&, d, d>` behaves.

Answer (score -1):

#4 is ill-formed, I'm surprised it compiles. For one thing, a double can't be used as a non-type template parameter. For another thing, a class template uses the same rules as function templates for partial ordering. The standard provides an example of the "imaginary" functions generated to perform the ordering:

```
template<int I, int J, class T> class X { };
template<int I, int J> class X<I, J, int> { }; // #1
template<int I>        class X<I, I, int> { }; // #2
template<int I, int J> void f(X<I, J, int>); // A
template<int I>        void f(X<I, I, int>); // B
```

For your example, it would look something like this:

```
template <typename T, T n1, T n2>
struct foo { 
};

template <typename T, T n1, T n2>
void bar(foo<T, n1, n2>)
{
    std::cout << "a";
}

template <typename T, T a>
void bar(foo<T, a, a>)
{
    std::cout << "b";
}
```

Template argument deduction is used to determine which function is more specialized than the other. A `double&` should be deduced as a `double` and so both specializations should be equal, aka ambiguous for `bar(foo<double&, d, d>{});`. Lo and behold GCC and Clang complain:

> **GCC error**
>
> main.cpp:14:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution
>   failed: main.cpp:26:29: note:   mismatched types 'double&' and
>   'double'
>
> ```
>  bar(foo<double&, d, d>{});
>                          ^
> ```
>
> **Clang error**
>
> note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T =
>   double &]: deduced non-type template argument does not have the same
>   type as the its corresponding template parameter ('double' vs 'double
>   &')

And again, if you remove the reference, they both correctly complain about using `double` as a non-type template parameter.

I'm not going to test the rest, but you may find similar results.

Comment: "For one thing, a double can't be used as a non-type template parameter." But an lvalue reference to `double` can.

Comment: ...and the deduction failures you are complaining about is caused by [a defect in the standard](http://wg21.link/cwg2091).

Comment: The second thing makes sense: "the same reference" is only usually exposed as "the pointers are the same".  The OP seems to want this "same" to work with template pattern matching, which seems philosophically excessive.

Answer (score -2):

I took the latest compilers and tried to explain the case of
foo<double&, d, d> behaver.

The foo function is declared as follow

```
// #1
template <typename T, T n1, T n2>
struct foo { 
    static const char* scenario() {
        return "#1 the base template";
    }
};

// #2
// partial specialization where T is unknown and n1 == n2
template <typename T, T a>
struct foo<T, a, a> { 
    static const char* scenario() {
        return "#2 partial specialization";
    }
};
```

The issue here is that the T type gets deduced by the call immediately as double and not double& as expected, and then it is implicit cast to double &.
That's why the different compilers behave in a different way.
changing the foo function to the following will solve the issue.

```
// #1
template <typename T, typename std::type_identity<T>::type n1, typename std::type_identity<T>::type n2>
struct foo { 
  static const char* scenario() {return "#1 the basic: template <typename T, T n1, T n2>";}
};

// #2
// partial specialization where T is unknown and n1 == n2
template <typename T, typename std::type_identity<T>::type a>
struct foo<T, a, a> { 
  static const char* scenario() {return "#2 partial specialization: template<typename T, T a> foo<typename T, a, a>";}
};
```

Comment: _"The issue here is that the T type gets deduced by the call immediately as double and not double&"_ No deduction occurs here. The type is explicitly specified during instantiation since these are class templates. The only way deduction *could* occur is with CTAD -- which is not being used here. This also fails to explain why there is a difference between gcc and clang, and which behavior is correct.

Comment: @Human-Compiler Template argument deduction is done to match the template arguments against the partial specialization (https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.partial.match#2) and indeed Clang behaves as expected if the type of the non-type template arguments are made non-deduced: https://godbolt.org/z/Yoj1Koqr8. (However, `foo` is a class template, not a function.)