# Equality of int&'s in template parameters

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, template-specialization, non-type-template-parameter

Suppose we have the following program:

```
template <class T, T n1, T n2>
struct Probe { 
    static const int which = 1;
};

template <class T, T n>
struct Probe<T, n, n> { 
    static const int which = 2;
};


int i = 123;

const int myQuestion = Probe<int&, i, i>::which;
```

I am pretty sure, that `myQuestion` should be `2` regardless of the version of C++ standard, but compilers disagree upon it. MSVC and clang say that it is `2` until C++14, and `1` since C++17. See the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/efETKzTo3). What is the truth?

My investigation so far:

- I have found one relevant sentence in the C++ standard. It was there in [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.type#1.6), [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.type#1.6), [C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.type#1.6) and [C++20](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.type#2.7). It did not change.
- If you remove the parameter `T` from the example code, all compilers agree, that `myQuestion` is `2`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6cW8GGEod).

Comment: Shouldn't `i` be `const` at least?

Comment: First `i` should be a **constant expression** when passing as template argument. Add `constexpr` or `const` for it.

Comment: Looks like the program is ill-formed since `i` is not a constant expression in your case. If you make it a constant expression, the program will no longer compile in any version.

Comment: Definitely an interesting Q. References are meant to be translucent in the type system.  Not sure how that may interplay with template equivalence checks however.

Comment: @AnoopRana - it's not ill-formed. For god's sake, it's a [mre], check it before commenting. A **reference** to an object with static storage duration is permissable in constant expressions, **even when** the referent is not const.

Comment: @AnoopRana Same error with contexpr/const int&: https://godbolt.org/z/a5Mrj4M53

Comment: @AnoopRana - And you missed the point of mine. It already is valid in constant expressions.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I think you're right[in which case i'll delete my comments] but i can't find the exact statement that you quoted: *"A reference to an object with static storage duration is permissable in constant expressions, even when the referent is not const"*. Can you put a link here for me?

Comment: @AnoopRana - https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#11 should have the gist of it.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ok then shouldn't [this](https://godbolt.org/z/h7ajqhnan) work without error? As you said, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/h7ajqhnan) we have a reference `ref` to an object `i` with static storage duration. Then `ref` can be used as size of an array.  Am i missing something?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369129 but can't be targetted because it doesn't have an upvoted/accepted answer.

Comment: @AnoopRana - Accessing the object's value in a constant expression requires it to satisfy additional constraints so the value is usable (in that case it should be constexpr indeed). Referring to the object alone (like in the OP, on surface level) doesn't require anything from the value.

Comment: @cigien: It's not a good idea to mark my question as a duplicate of that [long question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369129). Even if my question is answered there, since it's so long, it would be difficult for the readers to extract information from that.

Comment: Ok, I don't have an issue with that. It *is* a duplicate, but it's not exactly a question that gets asked a lot, so it's not a big deal to leave it open. I wouldn't dispute the closure either, i.e. I'm fine not voting either way.